# how to use for loop to save one or more values in a variable form an array ?in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a array as $result which i got from this select operation.I am using codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from($table);
$this->db->where('User_Id',$User_Id);
$query = $this->db->get();
$results = $query->result();
$result = $results[0];
```

I want to save this values in a variables .what i am doing is

```
$HeightFrom=$result->HeightFrom;
$HeightTo=$result->HeightTo;
$MaritalStatus=$result->MaritalStatus;
$Religion=$result->Religion;
$MotherTongue=$result->MotherTongue;
$Community=$result->Community;
$ProfileCreatedby=$result->ProfileCreatedby;etc....
```

but i have 50 values in arrary .so want to use for loop .what can I do ?how to write the for loop code .
and my question is using for loop i want to save the array value as variable name which contains the value

Comment: what you want to do ??

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the results and assign it to a variable at the same time, like this:

```
while ($result = $query->result()) {

    $HeightFrom=$result->HeightFrom;
    $HeightTo=$result->HeightTo;
    $MaritalStatus=$result->MaritalStatus;
    $Religion=$result->Religion;
    $MotherTongue=$result->MotherTongue;
    $Community=$result->Community;
    $ProfileCreatedby=$result->ProfileCreatedby
}
```

It will just stop when no more records are there to fetch.

**Note**: In its current format it will overwrite your variables in each iteration of the loop - you have to do something with it, for example output it or save it in another array.

Comment: :if $result->HeightFrom;is empty means it will show a error right ?so is there any other way to find the array ['HeightFrom'] is present or not.and if it present i should save it in a variable

Comment: No, it shouldn't show an error in this case. It only assigns the value to a new variable - in this case null, '' or any other value that is assigned to `$result->HeightFrom`.

Comment: if $result->HeightFrom ;is not present then?so only i need to make automatic

Comment: Then there's possibly no data in your table, field or something else went wrong. try `print_r($query)` to see if your query returned something.

Comment: :yes correct . so only i want to make it as .if present save it in variable ,else dont want.this the exact question i had in my mind

Comment: @vickysoft: Error handling was not a part of your question. We cannot write all the code for you, just solve one problem at the time. Please post a new question for a new problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this would do:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value ){
  $$key = $value;
}
```

**$$key** will set variables with the name of each key. For example if key is **HeightFrom**, the variable would be **$HeightFrom**, so you can call these variables, all 50 of them.